# Powerquery - Index column which restarts based on a grouped column

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a table which contains 2000 entries. I want to add an index column to the table which will "reset" for each unique entrie in another column.

Hopefully the below table will help explain it

| Team Name | Library Name | Index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Team 1 | **January** | **1** |
| Team 1 | January | 2 |
| Team 1 | January | 3 |
| Team 1 | **February** | **1** |
| Team 1 | February | 2 |
| Team 1 | February | 3 |
| Team 1 | **March** | **1** |
| Team 1 | March | 2 |
| Team 1 | March | 3 |
| Team 1 | March | 4 |
| Team 1 | **April** | **1** |
| Team 1 | April | 2 |
| Team 1 | April | 3 |
| Team 1 | April | 4 |
| Team 1 | April | 5 |

I just can't get my head around how to achieve this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start table:

[image]

Group by:

[image]

Add new column:

[image]

Expand and remove old columns:

[image]